# Twilio call forward with call recording

Tags: twilio

I am new to this and want to do something I thought was simple.
Caller dials Twilio Number and the calls gets forwarded and recorded upon answer at the forwarded number. I made a Twimlet that forwards the call just fine - how do I add the record function to the forwarding Twimlet?
The forwarding code is:
http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=952-xxx-2362&CallerId=714-xxx1848&Timeout=20&FailUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fforward%3FPhoneNumber%3D952-xxx-2362%26CallerId%3D714-xxx-1848%26Timeout%3D20%26&

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. It is also unclear to me where the recorded conversations are stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

what you are trying to implement will not work.
the forward twiml does not set the record attribute.

you would need to create your own version of this where you are setting the record attribute to true.
that would be your first step, you would then need to configure the StatusCallback method, because when the call has ended, this method will get called and you will be able to receive the RecodingUrl and then continue with your business requirements.

you can see more details about the call verb here
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional

Answer (score 1):

Take your existing twimlet, add a record parameter to it:

```
record="record-from-answer"
```

Then take the entire thing and paste it into the [echo twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo). This becomes your new Request URL. Super easy, especially if you don't want to write and host your own XML.