# Twilio forwarded call recording using Twimlet

Tags: twilio, recording

I am using call forwarding twimlet to forward calls. Everything works, except recording.

I've tried various ways (adding &Record=true parameter or record="record-from-answer" parameter), but I haven't been able to get it working.

My original Twimlet that is working well
http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=+333555123&FailUrl=https_url_working

I've tried using Twimlet echo, suggested by Serg Chernata, in this topic
[Twilio call forward with call recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750614/twilio-call-forward-with-call-recording)

But if I add that url to request URL, then it says system error, when I'm trying to make a call.

Does anybody know how to get this working without hosting XML?

Comment: Hey Marko, Megan from Twilio here. Really glad you figured that out. I was just about to respond. You should put the solution as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Megan, moved the answer to different post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. 
Twimlet echo generator takes input as XML and outputs the Twimlet echo command, which can be used as Request URL.

To get the recording to work, just paste this

```
<Response>
  <Dial record="true">+37255610091</Dial>
</Response>
```

to https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo

It will generate Twimlet Echo URL. Then copy-paste that to Twilio Request URL form. And then it should work.